# Asynchronous emailing

Tags: email, wp-cron, wp-mail, events

Whenever a user performs an action involving sending out email notifications, it takes a long time to process and therefore the user must wait a few seconds until the resulting page is loaded.

As a solution I wanted to do the emailing asynchronously.

To do this, I used `wp_schedule_single_event` and I set the time parameter to `time()` (ie: immediate).

This works well, however, if back to back emails are sent, they don't all get sent. I don't understand why. The docs mention:

> Attempts to schedule an event after an event of the same name and
>   $args will also be ignored.

But my $args are not the same.

Could the problem have something to do with:

> The action will fire off when someone visits your WordPress site, if
>   the schedule time has passed.

since a post might be made before someone has had a chance to visit the site and trigger the previous post's task?

Is this the preferred way of achieving asynchronous emailing?

Thank you.

(aside: I will have a load balancer pinging my site regularly. Will this be enough to trigger the scheduled actions if they have passed their scheduled time?)

**The code:**
The Util functions:

```
     public static function send_asynch_email( $email, $subject, $message, $headers )
    {
        wp_schedule_single_event( time(), 'asynch_email', array($email, $subject, $message, $headers));
    }

    public static function send_email( $to, $subject, $message, $headers = '', $attachments = array() )
    {
        return wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
    }
```

And in my `functions.php` file:

```
add_action('asynch_email', 'trigger_asynch_email', 10, 4);
function trigger_asynch_email( $email, $subject, $message, $headers ){
    Util::send_email($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Comment: Do you mind adding some code examples for us?

Comment: I doubt that a simple IP ping will do it.  Maybe a separate CRON job at your host, which references a page at your site:  `* * * * * wget -O - http://mywebsite.com/myaction.php/ >/dev/null 2>&1`  (runs once every minute, you can change of course...)

Comment: can not really help without code !

Comment: updated the question with code.